# ¿Qué es la coma luego de la asignación de una variable? ¿Y qué es el .call luego de un .map?

Tags: javascript

Intento aprender cómo traer una serie de inputs del archivo HTML al JS y sólo pude encontrar un video donde lo hacían. Pero hay cosas que no entiendo, que nunca vi, y no encuentro donde aprenderlas...
(Nota: Les puso a todos los `<input>` del html un `class = "inputNumeros"` )

Primero no entiendo por qué luego del `document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumeros")` puso una coma en vez de un punto-y-coma. Y a raíz de eso no entiendo qué vendría a ser el *namesValues*. No es una variable porque no la declaró, ¿verdad? ¿Entonces qué es?
Luego el `.map.call` jamás lo había visto. Conozco el `.map`, sé que recorre todo el array y nos devuelve otro array con la misma longitud que el anterior. ¿Y entonces el `.call` para qué está? O sea, cuál es el razonamiento de lo que esta haciendo en esas ultimas 2 lineas de código?

```
function onclickButtonCalcularMediana(){
    var arrayInput = new Array();
    let inputNumerosValues = document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumeros"),
    namesValues = [].map.call(inputNumerosValues, function(datos){
            arrayInput.push(datos.value);
    })
};
```

Comment: El coma dice que ambos son LET.  Por ejemplo, LET x=1, y=2;  El resultado es que x es 1 y y es 2.  Es más corto como LET x=1; LET y=2;

Comment: Sea como sea, te recomiendo refactorizar el código. La legibilidad es **PÉSIMA**.

Comment: Si bien hiciste el esfuerzo de explicar qué entendés y qué no (¡genial!), recordá que el formato es _preguntar solo una cosa a la vez_. Evitá hacer múltiples preguntas en una sola.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez  la verdad que no se como refactorizarlo para que tenga una mejor legibilidad. No lo escribí yo y a penas estoy aprendiendo lo que escribió :/

Comment: Tal vez así lo entiendas mejor https://pastebin.com/5tBYZX8S. Ten en cuenta que en `arrayInput` van a guardarse todos los valores de los inputs que tengan la clase `inputNumeros`. Puedes poner un `console.log(arrayInput);` al final de la función para que lo compruebes.

Comment: ahora entendí mucho más, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

para el primer caso de

> Primero no entiendo por qué luego del "document.getElementsByClassName("inputNumeros")" puso una coma en vez de un punto-y-coma. Y a raíz de eso no enitendo que vendria a ser el "namesValues".

cuando en javascript haces algo como `let var1, var2, var3;` en teoría estás declarando 3 variables en una misma linea, que es lo que hace el código con inputNumerosValues  y namesValues.
Acá puedes ver ejemplos del uso del `.call()` https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call